# How to insert MS Chart from a WinForms app into an Outlook email using a Memory Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, outlook

I'm trying to get an MS chart into an outlook email. I want to avoid saving it onto the desktop so I decided to use a `MemoryStream`. This is what I've put together so far:

```
MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
chart1.SaveImage(s, ChartImageFormat.Png);
s.Position = 0;

OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
chart1.SaveImage(s, ChartImageFormat.Png);
chart1.SaveImage(s, ChartImageFormat.Png);
mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><body>This is the <strong>funky</strong> message body</body></html>" ;


mailItem.Attachments.Add(s);

//Set a high priority to the message
mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
mailItem.To = "testemail@gmail.com";
mailItem.Display(false);
//mailItem.Send();
```

I just can't seem to find a way to get the `MemoryStream` into the email.

Comment: Not really sure, but the Outlook Object Model does not seem to support adding a file attachment from memory. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553.aspx). I would suggest you take a look at [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm).

Comment: Are you trying to create an RTF email with an embedded OLE object (Chart) or an HTML email with an embedded image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook supports sending email using SMTP. So you can use [`SmtpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to send an email. Then you can send the image as attachment or put the image in the email body:

```
var body = @"Here is the chart: <br/> <img src=""$CONTENTID1$""/>";
var CONTENTID1 = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "");
body = body.Replace("$CONTENTID1$", "cid:" + CONTENTID1);
var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, null, "text/html");
var stream = new MemoryStream();
this.chart1.SaveImage(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
stream.Position = 0;
LinkedResource imagelink1 = new LinkedResource(stream, "image/png");
imagelink1.ContentId = CONTENTID1;
imagelink1.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink1);

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("someone@outlook.com");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("someone@example.com"));
mail.Subject = "Subject";
mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

client.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("someone@outlook.com", "password");
client.Send(mail);
```

This way, the chart image will be shown in body of email:

[image]

Comment: I got this error

  The server response was: 5.7.3 Requested action aborted; user not authenticated

Comment: Check your client settings like Host, Port, etc which are at the end of above code. These settings are very important and I used exactly these settings and it sends an email from my outlook.com account to another account.

Comment: It seems the post answers your question. Also it's the answer to your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943115/save-image-on-my-computer-as-html-to-embed-in-email) which I had not seen yet.