# Save image on my computer as HTML to embed in email?

Tags: c#, html, .net

I'm trying to convert an image I have on my computer to HTML and embed it into an email:

This is what I've tried so far:

```
chart1.SaveImage("C:\\My Chart\\mychart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);


OutlookApp outlookApp = new OutlookApp();
MailItem mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);

mailItem.Subject = "This is the subject";
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\My Chart\\mychart.png");
var b64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
var dataUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + b64String;
mailItem.HTMLBody = dataUrl ;


//Set a high priority to the message
mailItem.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh;
mailItem.To = "email@email.com";
mailItem.Display(false);
```

This doesn't work, it shows up as a bunch of code in the actual email

Comment: Lots of email clients wont display inline base64 images, last I looked that included Outlook

Comment: Take a look at this answer from another question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9110164/6220820) It looks like you need to embed it as an attachment.

Comment: @AlexK. That explains why this isn't working now :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [base64 encoded images in email signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures)

Comment: Using `DataUri` is not recommended because of weak support in most of mail clients, I tested it with *Outlook.com(web)* and *OutlookWebAccess(web)* and *Office Outlook(Windows)* and *Outlook(windows 8.1)* and unfortunately it worked only on *OutlookWebAccess(web)* Instead I recommend you using attachment contentid. For more information read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767314/how-to-use-razor-engine-for-email-templating-with-image-src).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Building Proper HTML**

Since you appear to be sending the body as HTML, try building an `<img>` tag and setting the `src` of it to your Base 64 encoded image data :

```
// Set the body of your email to an image that contains your Base64-encoded image
mailItem.HTMLBody = String.Format("<img src='{0}' />",dataUrl);
```

This should build your `<img>` tag as expected, however if will appear or not will be a matter of support.

**Checking Browser and Client Support**

It's worth noting that [while most major browsers will support Base64 URLs, many have issues and limitations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datauri). Additionally, some e-mail clients [may not support them either](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2013/02/embedded-images-in-html-email/) as seen below :

[image]

Comment: This gets an image into the email, but it's a red x with the error message. can't load image. Maybe I didn't save the image correctly?

Comment: That's likely a matter of support. I've provided an example that demonstrates that Outlook 2007+ may natively block images from appearing in such a matter. You may want to consider an approach similar to [the link provided in Vortex's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9110164/6220820) on another approach for handling this.